# NgRoute is not available

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've created a web app, that works perfectly. Now I need to create almost exactly the same html page with a slightly different controller. I'm attempting to use ngRoute but it is not working, I am also not 100% confident that my route will get me the results I want.

When I try to run my code I get this error: Failed to instantiate module ngRoute due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngRoute' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Edit: I've added Angular-route.js my index file and I am now getting the error "Unknown provider: $routeProvider"

Can someone tell me why my routes are not working?

Here is my code:

### App.js (Route section only)

```
app = angular.module('rcr_sched', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
       function($routeProvider){
       When('/',{
           templateUrl: 'index.html',
           controller: 'main'
       }).
       When('/drill',{
           templateUrl: 'drill.html',
           controller: 'drill'
       }).
       otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
        });  

}
         ]);
```

### Index.html

```
  <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="app.css" />
          <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" scr="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="js/domo.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>      
      </head>
      <body ng-app="rcr_sched" ng-controller="main">
          <div id="mydiv" ng-view>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th id="printc"><button id="print" class="fa fa-print fa-2x" onclick="print('#mydiv')"></button></th>
                    <th ng-repeat="prop in columns">{{prop.date}}</th>
                </tr>  
                <tr ng-repeat="r in data">
                    <td id="linkc">
                    <button id="link" class="fa fa-plus-square fa-1x" onclick="href='#/drill'"></button>
                    </td>  
                    <td align="center" ng-repeat="prop2 in columns" class="{{getColor(r.TeamRank, r.Team, prop2.title)}}" style="{{isPTO(prop2.title, 'PTO' + prop2.title, r['PTO' + prop2.title])}}">
                        {{r[prop2.title]}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
          </div>      
      </body>
    </html>
```

### Drill.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="app.css" />
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.0-rc.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/domo.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>      
  </head>
  <body ng-app="rcr_sched" ng-controller="main">
      <div id="mydiv">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th><button id="print" class="fa fa-print fa-2x" onclick="print('#mydiv')"></button></th>
                <th ng-repeat="prop in columns">{{prop.date}}</th>
            </tr>  
            <tr ng-repeat="r in data">
                <td>
                <button id="link" class="fa fa-plus-square fa-1x" onclick="href='#/'"></button>
                </td>  
                <td align="center" ng-repeat="prop2 in columns" class="{{getColor(r.TeamRank, r.Team, prop2.title)}}" style="{{isPTO(prop2.title, 'PTO' + prop2.title, r['PTO' + prop2.title])}}">
                    {{r[prop2.title]}}
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
      </div>      
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change below things in your code :

1. You just need to import file in single root HTML(should be `index.html`).
2. `angular.js` file needs to be import before any other file, in your case `angular-route.js`
3. There should be only 1 `ng-app` tag, remove extra from `drill.html`
4. No need of providing `ng-controller` in html as this is already defined in `route config.`
5. separate your route `index.html` from routing, you can take out the necessary part of `default route(/)` in some other file. something like `home.html`
6. take the `<table>.../<table>` part into separate routing html files(`home.html, drill.html`), which `ng-view` will take care..

See this [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/I2OIFsN38WSZzoHs2Prf?p=preview) for example.

Basically your app routing should be only inside `ng-view`, In general template like:

```
 <body>
    <header>
        <h1>App title</h1>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#/drill">drill</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I feel like this would work, however now it is returning a different error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. Do you know why this would happen?

Comment: most probably issue of routing, your `/` route needs to be point to extracted html, not to Index html. Like in attached plunker link, It points to `home.html`, not index

Answer (score -1):

The router is a separate angular file and should be added as such in your index.html:

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I've added it and now I have another error: Unknown provider: $routeProvider, Do I have a typo that I am not catching?